# Are there future tenses for Japanese verbs?

Tags: verbs

I am unable to find an example of a future tense Japanese verb.

Comment: No, it's the same as the present, and you must use context to determine it. But then again, English doesn't have a future tense either.

Comment: I believe that the word will is used for the future tense in most cases

Comment: That's not a tense. Will is a modal verb in English. Time is not the same thing as tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there isn't a future tense in Japanese. The dictionary form of the verb acts as both present and future. The difference is inferred from context and the surrounding words.

A simple example:

> ケーキをよく食べる
>   I often eat cake
>   明日ケーキを食べる
>   I will eat cake tomorrow

Comment: think of ikimasu. I am going....Oh when are you going? There is no need for future tense. You can use Ima for now if you need to